# In Magit, is it possible to know when an unstaged change happened? How to find that information?

Tags: magit, files, git

I have a repository under version control and I am using Magit as an interface to git.

I can see one unstaged change in a file after executing `magit-status` (`C-x g`). This means the file was changed and the change was saved.

However, I can't see when this change happened in Magit's `magit-status` dashboard. I also tried using `magit-blame`. But it only shows information about date (and author) after the change was committed (which is not the case).

Is it possible to know when the unstaged change was made? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unstaged changes have not been committed yet. Neither magit or git has any idea of when the changes happened, they only see the file is different to what was committed.

You can check the modification time of the file, though. If you use `dired-x`, you can just press <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> to invoke `dired-jump` to open a dired buffer with point at the file in question with the last modification time displayed.

Comment: Thanks. Dired was just in front of my eyes...